# NSNull cc_componentsForMonthDayAndYear in Kal calender error ios

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, nullreferenceexception

I am developing iPhone application that persists data to a SQLite3 database.
Also I am using Kal calender. Here I able to get Calender successfully But when I inserted Date from SQLite3 database. It get crashed by giving error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull cc_componentsForMonthDayAndYear]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3f8a85e0'
```

I am not getting what's wrong going here.. 
I have go through several search pages..
I tried to solve this by two way feting double as NSDate like

```
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:sqlite3_column_double(selectstmt, 4)]
```

and this way to Fetching NSDate using NSDateFormatter `[dateformate dateFromString dateString]`

please help me regarding this ASAP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think some values are not retrieved correctly,

Check whether the object that is used to call  "componentsForMonthDayAndYear" contains value.

provide a null check before calling "componentsForMonthDayAndYear" method which will help you to avoid this type of exception

```
if (object != NSNull.null) {
   [object cc_componentsForMonthDayAndYear];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Arshad.. U absolutely right.. I was passing NULL value.. i.e. NSDate, due to ARC. So I changed at Object while passing NSDate instead of [NSDate retain] to [NSDate copy]; Now its work perfectly... Thanxs Again..